# What UML Diagram for high level relations between both components/subsystems and actors

Tags: uml

I'm trying to figure out which UML diagram I should use for a structural representation of both components/subsystems and actors.

A component diagram doesn't allow for actors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a component diagram and put actors in. It is perfectly reasonable to do this.

Comment: Agreed. UML is supposed to help with communication. If adding an actor to a diagram is helpful, do it. Don't let the general rules become a straightjacket.

Answer (score 0):

Component diagram is a right place. If an actor is a man - it cannot appear on the component diagram, but if it is an any soft/hardware - it is ok.

Imagine that in your system there is an DataBase actor. In this case you will have an appropriate component on your component diagram